# VBA I'm Stumped! Seemingly simple Horizontal Aligment

Tags: vba, formatting

I've got something that's really confusing me.

This one line of code is throwing up errors:

```
Worksheets(Options).Range(Cells(OptCurrentRow, OptCurrentCol)).HorizontalAligment = xlCenter
```

I've tried with Range, without Range, referencing a different cell vs. not, but I get the error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. Please help! Thanks.

PS. All of those references exist and work fine throughout the rest of my code

Comment: Just spent hours looking for an answer to this, but just had to dig into every property I could find and eventually was able to set it!!!  lol.   
Get your Range, and then set the alignment twice, in this order:
excelSheet.Range("RangeNameOrAddress").Style.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
excelSheet.Range("RangeNameOrAddress").HorizontalAlignment         = xlLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HorizontalAligment** is misspelt. **HorizontalAlignment**

You should remove the .Range part as well:

```
Worksheets(Options).Cells(optCurrentRow, optCurrentCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

(`Cells` is already a `Range`).

Comment: I hate everything. Thanks, haha

Comment: I'm getting a new error now:

Unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property of the Range Class.

Comment: Are you running this from Excel VBA? If not, then use -4108 in place of `xlCenter`. Try this anyway. Check Tools/References (in the VBA Editor) to see if any references are MISSING. Try to set the alignment manually for this cell in the worksheet, see if it allows you to.